# How to remove one part on window.location in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check window.location, if have "IsReload=True" keyword, I'll remove it. For example: this my window.location:

```
http://localhost/Demo/User/ManagedUsersTab?isReload=True
```

I want to remove "?isReload=True" and no reload this page, just remove it. How can I do it. This my snippet:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?isReload=True") > -1) {
            window.location.replace('@Url.Action("ManagedUsersTab", "User")');
        }
```

this snippet reload page

Comment: `window.location.href.split('?')[0]`

Comment: Changing `location.href` effects a page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var regex = /(\?|&)isReload=True/;
var location = window.location.href;
if(regex.test(location)){
    window.location =location.replace(regex, '$1')
}
```

Comment: What's $1? I don't understand

Comment: it is the first group from the regex `?|&` it is used to make sure other possible parameters from the url is maintained as it is